# Ion-tabs, incorrect component display

Tags: ionic-framework, vuejs3

node v16.13.2

my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    ...
    "@ionic/vue": "^6.0.13",
    "@ionic/vue-router": "^6.0.13",
    "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.2",
    "axios": "^0.25.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.5",
    "vue": "^3.2.31",
    "vue-axios": "^3.4.0",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.14",
    "vuex": "^4.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.17.0",
    "@babel/eslint-plugin": "^7.16.5",
    "@capacitor/cli": "3.4.1",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/compiler-sfc": "^3.2.31",
    "eslint": "^8.12.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "^3.1.1"
  },
```

App.vue

```
<template>
    <ion-app><ion-page>

        <router-view />

    </ion-page></ion-app>
</template>
```

cart index component

```
<ion-content>
Cart
</ion-content>
```

cart archive component

```
<ion-content>
Archive 
</ion-content>
```

router

```
{
        path: "/cart/",
        name: "cartTabsNav",
        component: () => import("@/cart/TabsNav.vue"),
        children: [
            {
                path: '',
                redirect: 'index',
            },
            {
                path: "index",
                name: "cartIndexAction",
                component: () => import("@/cart/IndexAction.vue"),
            },
            {
                path: "archive",
                name: "cartArchiveAction",
                component: () => import("@/cart/ArchiveAction.vue"),
            },
        ],
    },
```

component TabsNav.vue

```
<ion-page>
    <ion-content>
    <ion-tabs>

        <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
        <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
            <ion-tab-button tab="index" href="/cart/index">
                <ion-icon :icon="cart"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>Cart</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>

            <ion-tab-button tab="archive" href="/cart/archive">
                <ion-icon :icon="reorderFourOutline"></ion-icon>
                <ion-label>Orders</ion-label>
            </ion-tab-button>
        </ion-tab-bar>

    </ion-tabs>
    </ion-content>
</ion-page>
```

But I see double layers with tabs! More on the screen.

[image]

And when I touch on the tabs I see this.

[image]

This is code from docs `ionicframework.com` https://ionicframework.com/docs/vue/navigation#working-with-tabs

I don't know what else to add, but the validator of the question asks so.

Comment: my suggestion is to start with the tabs starter template and go from there, this way you are sure you are starting with a proper foundation - https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/start

Comment: OMG, just need in the App.vue will replace `router-view` on `ion-router-outlet`. **But!!!** It doesn't work with `:key="$route.fullPath"`. Team developers says: **that need a code reproduction**.

It is sad.

[https://githubhelp.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24996](https://githubhelp.com/ionic-team/ionic-framework/issues/24996)